# Did Kant believe the enlightened and moral republican public could make up for legislative and executive institutions?

Tags: political-philosophy, kant, philosophy-of-law

Kant's theoretical work Perpetual Peace could be seen as limited insofar as he didn't really provide any detailed thoughts on the legislative and executive institutions that would make international law reality. Could it be said that he relies on the enlightened and moral republican public to make up for this? Explain how this strategy could work, and whether you think its sufficient.

Comment: What did you mean with "publics"? The public of every single state? Or public figures? Also, could you maybe share what you found out already? Where does your idea come from, exactly? Could you provide the relevant passages?

Comment: This question seems some undergraduate homework.